# Second form on a PHP page won't run

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have two forms on a page. When I run the first, it works as intended, but the second, despite having different form id and all the elements being named, will not (it attempts to run the first form, I think, but with no elements being posted it will return no result).

The second form is in the "Roles" section.

Here is the code - any help is appreciated!

```
/***** Section: Rights *****/
echo '

        <!-- div: Edit -->
        <div id="dashboardPanelWrapper">
            <div id="sectionArrow"></div>
            <div id="dashboardPanelTitle">User rights and privileges</div>
            <div id="dashboardPanelContent">';


            echo "<div id='DV_simple_wrapper_wide'>";

            echo "<table width='60%'><tr><th>Role</th><th>Staff</th><tr>";
            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT rightName FROM ".$dbName.".rights WHERE siteLimit='gpvwc' AND rightName!='ADMIN' ORDER BY rightName ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                    $role=$row[0];

                    echo "<tr><td>$role</td><td>";

                //  $query2= "SELECT userId FROM ".$dbName.".rights WHERE rightName='$role' AND siteLimit='gpvwc'";
                    $query2 = "SELECT CONCAT (u.firstName, ' ',u.lastName) AS username, r.head FROM ".$dbName.".rights r LEFT JOIN ".$dbName.".users u ON r.userId=u.id WHERE r.rightName='$role' AND r.siteLimit='gpvwc' ORDER BY r.head DESC, username ASC";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
                            $name=$row[0];
                            $head=$row[1];
                            if ($head=='1') { $name="<b>$name, </b>"; }
                            if ($head=='0') { $name="$name, "; }
                            echo "$name";
                        }
                        echo "</td></tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";    

            echo "<form id='1' action='' method='post'>";

            $usersAsArray = $user->listUsers($banned=false);

            echo '<div id="defButtonWrapperH">';
            echo '<select id="DriverAppealEvent" class="defSelectV" style="min-width: 70px; margin-bottom: 10px;"  onchange="submitTarget(this.value);">';
                echo '<option value="0">--</option>';

                foreach ($usersAsArray as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$key.'"';
                        if (isset($target) && $target == $key)
                            echo 'selected';
                    echo '>'.$value.'</option>';
                }

            echo '</select>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
            echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';

            $userToEdit = false;
            if ($target) {
                $userToEdit = $user->userToView($target);
                // Check if any rights given for this user and update form if any
                $query = "SELECT u.*, r.rightName, r.countryLimit, r.siteLimit, r.isActive, r.head FROM ".$dbName.".users u
                LEFT JOIN ".$dbName.".rights r ON r.userId=u.id WHERE u.id=".$target;

                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    if ($row['rightName'] != '') {
                        $userToEdit['rights'][] = array(
                            'rightName' => $row['rightName'],
                            'rightCountryLimit' => $row['countryLimit'],
                            'rightSiteLimit' => $row['siteLimit'],
                            'rightIsActive' => $row['isActive'],
                            'rightHead' => $row['head']
                        );
                    }
                }
                mysql_free_result($result);

                // If the user has rights then write a table with all them plus options to revoke
                if (!empty($userToEdit['rights'])) {
                    drawUserRightsTable($userToEdit);
                }
            echo "</form>";
                // Draw selector with rights here so we can add new rights to this user

                $useradd=$userToEdit['id'];

                echo "<form id='addadmin' action='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Admins.php?op=add&user=$useradd' method='post'>";
                echo "Role: <select name='role'>";
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT rightName FROM ".$dbName.".rights WHERE rightName!='ADMIN' ORDER BY rightName ASC";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                    $righttoadd=$row[0];

                    echo "<option value='$righttoadd'>$righttoadd</option>";
                }
                echo "</select></br>";
                echo "Head: <input type='radio' name='head' value='0' checked> No <input type='radio' name='head' value='1'> Yes";
                echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
                MODW_Buttons_Button(Normal,Normal,Normal,Normal,None,$RKP,$id,BGenSu,$intern,$intcont);
                echo "</form>";

                //echo '<pre>';print_r($userToEdit);echo '</pre>';
            }

            echo "</div>";

echo '      </div>
        </div>';


/***** Section: Roles *****/
echo '

        <!-- div: Edit -->
        <div id="dashboardPanelWrapper">
            <div id="sectionArrow"></div>
            <div id="dashboardPanelTitle">Disciplinary Committee Roles</div>
            <div id="dashboardPanelContent">';

            echo "<div id='DV_simple_wrapper_wide'>";

            echo "<table width='60%'><tr><th>Series</th><th>Staff</th><th>&nbsp;</th><tr>";
            $query = "SELECT id, compName FROM ".$dbName.".competitions WHERE active='1' AND id!='10' ORDER BY id ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

                    $compid=$row[0];
                    $compName=$row[1];

                    echo "<tr><td><b>$compName</b></td><td>";

                //  $query2= "SELECT userId FROM ".$dbName.".rights WHERE rightName='$role' AND siteLimit='gpvwc'";
                    $query2 = "SELECT CONCAT (u.firstName, ' ',u.lastName) AS username, r.role, u.id, r.series FROM ".$dbName.".DC_roles r LEFT JOIN ".$dbName.".users u ON r.user=u.id WHERE r.series='$compid' ORDER BY username ASC";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
                            $name=$row[0];
                            $role=$row[1];
                            $userid=$row[2];
                            $seriesid=$row[3];
                            if ($role=='1') { $name="<i>$name</i>"; }
                            if ($role=='0') { $name="$name"; }
                            echo "$name <a href='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Admins.php?op=DelDCRights&user=$userid&comp_id=$seriesid'><b>X</b></a></br>";
                        }
                        echo "</td></tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";    
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<form id='dcroles' action='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Admins.php?op=AddDCRights' method='post'>";
            echo "User: <select id='userDC' name='userDC'>";
            $query1 = "SELECT id, firstName, lastName FROM ".$dbName.".users ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC";
            $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {
                $DCuserId=$row[0];
                $DCfirstName=$row[1];
                $DClastName=$row[2];

                echo "<option value='$DCuserId'>$DClastName, $DCfirstName</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></br>";
            echo "</br>";
            echo "Series: <select id='seriesDC' name='seriesDC'>";
            $query = "SELECT id, compName FROM ".$dbName.".competitions WHERE active='1' AND id!='10' ORDER BY id ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                $DCcompId=$row[0];
                $DCcompName=$row[1];

                echo "<option value='$DCcompId'>$DCcompName</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></br>";
            echo "Third Checker: <input type='radio' id='head' name='head' value='0' checked> No <input type='radio' name='head' value='1'> Yes</br>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
            echo "</form>";
```

Comment: When you say "it won't run" do you mean it won't populate from SQL or it won't submit?

Comment: Your second form action doesn't look valid? 

action='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Admins.php?op=add&user=$useradd'

Comment: @TofuWarrior it returns to the same page, which is the end action of the first form, without entering anything into SQL (as the variables posted by the form are different).

Comment: @FrankW. hi Frank - what do you mean exactly? That form is the one that appears to be working - of course, some of the variables are either defined elsewhere or in the run-up to the action call.